# FluentAssertions Type check

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, fluent-assertions

I try to use **FluentAssertions** to check in my UnitTest, that the type of a property in a list of items is of a certain type.

```
myObj.Items.OfType<TypeA>().Single()
            .MyProperty1.GetType()
                .Should().BeOfType<TypeB>();
```

Unfortunately, my test fails with the following error message:

> Expected type to be
> TypeB,
> but found System.RuntimeType.

Why does it say, that it found `System.RuntimeType`?
I used the debugger to verify, that `MyProperty1`is of type `TypeB` and it is... am I using `.BeOfType<>` wrong?

Comment: Can You skip the .GetType()? You are asking not the MyProperty1's type, but the type's type. It's 1 level too deep.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Please skip the .GetType(). You are asking not the MyProperty1's type, but the type's type. It's 1 level too deep.

```
public class TypeB { }

public class TypeA
{
    public TypeB MyProperty1 { get; set; }

    public TypeA()
    {
        MyProperty1 = new TypeB();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        List<object> objects = new List<object>();
        objects.Add("alma");
        objects.Add(new TypeA());
        objects.OfType<TypeA>().Single().MyProperty1.Should().BeOfType<TypeB>();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh god my bad... the exception message was even pretty obvious.. thank you :-)